# Data Type of Named Range

Tags: vba, excel, date, variant

I have a named range in Excel called StartDates for instance. The named range only contains dates. Example code below:

```
Sub test2()
Dim dat_readdates() As Date

dat_readdates = Range("StartDates").Value

End Sub
```

This always results in the proverbial Run-time error '13': Type mismatch.

A simple change and it works fine.

```
Sub test2()
Dim var_readdates() As Variant

var_readdates = Range("StartDates").Value

End Sub
```

Is there a known rule that data must be read in as variant data type? Clearly for speed I would like to use the data type most appropriate to the data being read. 
Do I need to read it as variant and then use cDate to convert to a another variable of date type? Can I do a mass conversion such as:

```
dat_readdates = cDate(var_readdates)
```

Comment: What do you get if you check `Typename(var_readdates(1,1) )` ?  If your range has dates then it should already be `Date`...

Comment: @TimWilliams by then it should be by a `Variant/Date`, not a native VBA `Date`. OP would like to work with native variables :)

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately. Values are fetched from Excel as `Variant`s. When fetching a single cell, you *can* directly convert it to the appropriate type, i.e.

```
Dim x as Long
x = myCell.Value
```

In the code above, first `myCell.Value` is fetched as a `Variant`, then converted by VBA to long (to execute the assignment) if the conversion is possible, otherwise run-time error.

With multiple-cell ranges, it's more tricky. The `range.value` returns a *Variant Array*. Unfortunately, VBA does not provide automatic conversion of a Variant array into a typed array. Therefore the following wont work:

```
Dim x() as Long
x = myRange.Value
```

VBA does not allow conversion of arrays like with simple variables; even if the programmer is sure that all the variants in the array are of the desired type (i.e. `Long` in the example above).

To emphasize, forget about excel; the following wont work in VBA:

```
Dim varArray() ' a variant array
varArray = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Dim longArray() as Long
longArray = varArray ' <-- type mismatch. No conversion from variant array to typed array.
```

Comment: Thanks A.S.H. Looping through the variant element by element and using cDate to create the Date array element by element seems to be the only way. I certainly want to avoid an element by element read from excel just so it comes into VBA as the correct type. A mass read and then element by element conversion feels like it might be faster.

Comment: @farmerandy: You are correct. REDIM the variant array to the correct size, and then assign to it from the **Value2** property of the Range. I have found this to be many times faster than an element-by-element processing, up to 30x faster when writing to the Range.

Comment: @farmerandy I agree, I dont see another way than a loop to convert to a typed array. Whether it is beneficial or not depends on subsequent code - certainly yes if massive computation with the typed variables will follow. Dont forget to get rid of the variant array to save space after conversion is complete. something like `Redim theVariantArray(0)`.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I'm trying to reconcile A.S.H and Peiter's comments. Pieter you seem to be saying to do a mass read but use the **Value2** property versus **Value**? A.S.H you seem to agree with my element by element conversion after mass read as a variant data type?

Comment: @farmerandy There's no contradiction between the two comments. Mine was about your intention (as I understood) to convert the variant array to a typed array **after** the variant array is fetched from Excel. The other comment was about how to fetch the variant array first.

Comment: @farmerandy Now is the conversion to typed array worth it? Most of the time No, but occasionally, as I said in the comment it all depends on what you want to do with it later...For massive computation, this conversion makes individual operations faster and also saves some space (> 50 %).

Comment: @A.S.H I'm only dealing with 3000-4000 rows of dates from the named range in Excel and the computations thereafter are pretty simple. I suspect my attempts at efficiency while honorable are not worth the investment in code. Thanks again.